# PyQt5 QPushButton fires more than once

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, qpushbutton

is there a way in Python3 PyQt5 to get the number of times a signal is connected to a slot i.e.:

QPushButton.clicked.connect(foo)

to have an idea of how many times the slot (foo) will be called upon emitting the signal ?

I am not talking of counters inside my code but a way to get that number from

where PyQt5 stores that info

Comment: No, there is no way to know that (that signal is also used by Qt's private API). I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Comment: I was just trying to understand how The signal-slot works. I got the message on my other duplicate post: ‘don’t make the connection more than once’

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc !! Your always kind to me, with answers and explanations. I know I should correct my code and think about it but it’s difficult to me and sometimes I got sidetracked out of my curiosity or attention/deficit disorder. I’ll try to read abou it as soon as I get the concept of API. Thank you again indeed

Comment: 1) If you want to use Qt then it is not necessary to know how Qt works, in the same way that to drive a car it is not necessary to know how the car's engine was built but it is enough with the car manual (Qt docs), 3) If you want to know the "engine" then you will have to check the engine manual (the C++ source code and the sip implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanically I would consider placing a

```py
print('any message') #like this you are directly notified via the console console or terminal,...
```

in each methode you will be calling, for example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
import sys
#import other modules

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        # Geometry of main window:
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 400)
        
        # create a Button Btn1
        self.Btn1 = QPushButton('Fire Button :)', self)
        self.Btn1.clicked.connect(self.Fire1)
        self.Btn1.move(0, 0)

        self.Btn2 = QPushButton('2nd Fire_Button :)', self)
        self.Btn2.clicked.connect(self.Fire2)
        self.Btn2.move(130, 0)

    def Fire1(self):
        print('Worked, Fired once!...details(...)')

    def Fire2(self):
        print('It is Working, but he needs to add his code! Thanks')
        self.setStyleSheet('background:rgba(80, 97, 15, 184);')
        self.resize(600, 210)
        pass
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

it's my answer is helping you (it's good!), otherwise provide us with more detailed infomations or sample of code you are working-on in order to better help you...

Comment: thanks for your answer. Printing tried that (non in this case) but kind of slow (or buffered don’t know) with PyQt5. Left PyQt5 after end 1st lockdown, now back with Biopython not sure I have access to my old Qt5 try-out. Thanks again

Comment: @pippo1980 Ok, it's Nothing